# If cell in row equals to number, than put in formula cell relative cell value to statement cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

According to screenshot I put below I've got trouble making A28 cell working. What I want to make is find in '17 row' date that equals to b27. if it finds it than I want to put in formula cell (where my if statement goes) value that is connected with this date  (in 22 rows). I have no idea how do create formula to achieve that. Anyone has idea how to do it? Thanks!

[Here is screenshot](http://puu.sh/4qAPF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HLOOKUP.

```
=HLOOKUP(B27, A17:E22, 6, 0)
```

This should do the trick.